# Flex run a method on EXACT time in video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video, flash-builder

I need to try and run a method on the exact time that a certain clip in  a video is playing.

so far I can do this with:

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="vid" currentTimeChange="checkTime()" x="208" y="49"/>
```

then in my script, i have

```
        function checkTime():void{

                label.text = new String(vid.currentTime);
                if(Math.round(vid.currentTime) == 12){
                    fademe();
                }
```

the above does work but the exact time i need is about 11.650 secs to run the method. If I take out the Math.round(), it doesn't work.

Please help, this is probably something simple but I an new to Flex and actionscript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the magnitude of current time.

```
   function checkTime():void{

            label.text = new String(vid.currentTime);
            int currentTime = Math.round(vid.currentTime*100) ;
            if( currentTime >= 1165 && currentTime <= 1170 ){
                fademe();
            }
```